# What is a simple way to integrate Facebook login into Rails 6 (or 5) app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-6

I have seen a few tutorials for integrating OmniAuth with Rails for Facebook login, but they are dated.

1. Is there a good reference for using OmniAuth (not omniauth-facebook) to integrate Facebook login into Rails 6 (or 5) app?
2. Do you need to use Devise?
3. Are there any other good and simple ways of integrating Facebook login besides OmniAuth?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessary use gem Devise to make login with Facebook. Gem `omniauth` is a gem different from gem `devise`. But use gem devise help you build your app faster.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2, devise is a pretty nice gem. It can do a lot of menial tasks for you, and I do recommend it if you like it. It's not a necessity though.

Now I'm not too familiar with omniauth but I have a lot of experience with Auth0, which is just amazing. It's really easy to do. And it's priced in such a way that a small app shouldn't need to pay anything.

Here's a guide on integrating Auth0 into rails: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/rails/01-login

Here's a guide on then using Facebook as a provider in Auth0: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/facebook

I honestly use Auth0 for every app I make now. It's that good.

I hope this answers part three for you, as you did ask for alternatives to omniauth.